# Consulta Bases de datos con POO en PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, poo

Tengo una clase que me devuelve la conexión, y otra clase que extiende esta anterior y utiliza en el método ComprobarUsuario(), esa conexión para hacer una consulta a la base de datos, pero me da error porque el método query me dice que le estoy llamando con un valor null.
CLASE CONSULTAS

```
class consultas extends conexion
{
private $conexion;

public function __construct() {
   $conexion = parent::conectar();
}
 
function comprobarUsuario()
{
        $sql = "select password from usuarios";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->query($sql,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $passwordBBDD=$stmt->fetch();

         if(password_verify($_POST['pass'], $passwordBBDD))
         {
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }  
    }
}
```

CLASE CONEXION

```
class conexion{
private $host = "localhost";
private $userName = "root";
private $dbName = "inmobiliaria";
private $clave = "";

 function conectar()
{
    try{
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbName; charset=utf8", $this->userName, $this->clave);
        
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        die("Error: " . $ex ->getMessage());
    } 
    return $conexion;
  }
}
```

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump($passowrdBBDD)`  en tu método `comprobarUsuarios()` que te arroja?

Comment: No me deja hacerlo porque como el error sale en el metodo query y $passowrdBBDD la defino justo despues, no lo hace. Pero ahi se deberia guardar la contraseña que hay en la BBDD que solo hay 1(cifrada)

Comment: Entonces, puedes hacer el dump en `$stmt` para ver que es lo que te regresa, de favor

Comment: $stmt esta vacío, al no hacer el query no guarda nada en $stmt

Comment: Si estás llamando al método con `parent::conectar()` creo que deberías definirlo como [estático](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php): `public static function conectar() { ... }`